# Difference between core and core-file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gdb, coredump

This is on Ubuntu 12.04, GDB version GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04

The application I work on does dump core more times than I care to. When I start gdb as follows, I don't get any usable backtrace.

```
gdb --core <path to core dump>
```

GDB does show the full path of the process that caused the core dump along with command line arguments.

When on the gdb prompt, if I execute commands

```
file <path to executable>
core-file <path to core dump>
```

I do get a usable backtrace.

What is the difference between --core command line option and core-file command executed from the gdb prompt?

Is there any way I can do this in the command line? After all, gdb does know the path to the executable and core file name.

Comment: can you do `gdb pathtoexecutable --core pathtocore` ?

Comment: @Mark: I can certainly do it. My main interest is why does gdb behaves differently. It certainly has process path and why does it not load symbols from process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can do this in command line.

Yes: `gdb /path/to/exe /path/to/core`

> My main interest is why does gdb behaves differently.

It doesn't.

Most UNIX systems, in order to conserve disk space, do not dump file-backed read-only pages (such as program code) into the core file -- that code is already on disk, so why write it again? (This is actually configurable: see `man core` and `coredump_filter`).

But these read-only pages contain symbols (what you see in `nm` and in `backtrace` output), so if you don't tell GDB where the executable file is, then it can't produce a  meaningful `backtrace`.

> After all, gdb does know the path to executable

No, it does not.

The kernel records *incomplete* info about the executable which produced the core. That info is unreliable:

- It may record relative path, e.g. `./a.out` and there is absolutely no guarantee that your current directory is the same at GDB analysis time as it was when the executable was invoked, and
- There is only space for 16 characters in `elf_prpsinfo.pr_fname[]`, and anything longer than that will be truncated.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Somethings are now clearer. I was confused because I have always seen gdb printing complete path in my particular case. I just end up copying that path for file command to gdb.